# Q Filter by alphabet

Tags: python, django

I attempting to create an alphabet filter in my project that will return all objects that begin with a specific letter.

This is my current view

```
class ArtistLetterView(ListView):
model = Artist
context_object_name = 'artist'
template_name = "artist/alpha_list.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    artist = Artist.objects.filter(
        Q(stage_name__startswith=query)
    )
    return artist
```

This is my URL

```
    path('letter_search/', views.ArtistLetterView.as_view(), name='list_letter'),
```

Currently if I manually enter a path like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/artist/letter_search/?q=D` it works.

How can I place this functionality into an href? Or am I completely doing this wrong?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "place this functionality into an href"? Do you mean like templating? e.g. `<a href="{% url 'list_letter' %}?q=D">`

Comment: Yes, that exactly, but I am unable to do this with numbers. For example, <a href="{% url 'list_letter' %}?q=[0-9]">#</a>. I am also asking if there is a more efficient way of executing this.